# How to use an entity with textContent

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to set the text content of an element using JavaScript. If I do this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('my-element')
el.textContent = '&times;'
```

The result is:

```
<div id="my-element">&amp;times;</div>
```

I tried using `\&` instead but that had no effect. How can I actually insert the entity into the text content?

Comment: `el.innerHTML = '&times;'`

Comment: @RandyCasburn Question updated; those were typos in the question, not the code

Comment: Awesome - now with your code edited, URLEncoded characters must be parsed by the HTML parser to output the correct output.  Therefore, you must set  `innerHTML` and not `textContent`. As you are now, it is doing what you asked - putting the text into the view. Make sense?

Comment: @j08691 That works, but I would like to know why textContent doesn't work

Comment: I explained it ^^^^^ and Nope explained it. \/ \/ \/ \/ in the answer.  What specific questions do you have??

Comment: @RandyCasburn Saw the explanations after I added that comment. It makes sense now; thanks. In my head, I guess I didn't really think of an entity as HTML :)

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help.

Comment: `&times;` is a HTML entity so in order to display it as such, and no just the text that it really is, you need to use `innerHTML` instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[**textContent**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) will **not** parse the HTML for you.

Use [**innerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) instead if you want the specified text to be parsed.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('my-element')
el.textContent = '&times;'

var el2 = document.getElementById('my-element2')
el2.innerHTML = '&times;'
```

```html
<div id="my-element"></div>
<div id="my-element2"></div>
```

Comment: Those two issues in my code were just typos, I updated the question. This answers my question still though. I wasn't really thinking of the entity as HTML content.

Comment: OK, I didn't see the edit. I update the answer to ignore the other parts then :)

Comment: @Nope thank you for sharing your detailed response, it just got me out of a pickle.

Comment: Great answer. Saved me from going down rabbit hole of htmlEncode and htmlDecode.

Answer (score 7):

As answered by others, you can't use HTML entities with `textContent`, 
and **there is rarely a need to do so**. Just use the character directly:

```
 el.textContent = "7 × 6 = 42";   // 7 &times; 6 = 42
 el.textContent = " ";
```

Make sure your files are encoded with `<meta charset=UTF-8>`. That's a requirement these days anyway.

Some HTML entities are problematic to handle directly, e.g. spaces like `&thinsp;` or `&nbsp;`. Here you can use a hexadecimal **Unicode escape sequence**.

Example:
 "NO-BREAK SPACE [NBSP]" is codepoint U+00A0.

As Javascript string just write `"\xA0"` or `"\u00A0"` for that.

```
// foo&nbsp;bar
el.textContent = "foo\xA0bar";
el.textContent = "foo\u00A0bar";
```

Comment: The second part of this answer, using hexadecimal Unicode, was the only way to concatenate existing node text with &zwj; for me (Chrome). In other words, `node.textContent = '/u200d' + node.TextContent`. InnerHTML with the entity and text content with direct use of the character did not work for this entity